# javascript argument scoping issue and function return

Tags: javascript, recursion, scoping

I have 2 slight issues with scoping in my function:

1. First is with scoping of the liberties argument. Everything goes fine until it reaches the main 'else' block when the variable gets reset when returning to a previous recursion. Putting liberties as a global variable fixes the problem, but that's not how it should be done...
2. the last return in the function gives undefined. Even though I can easily console.log those variables (they are correct in all cases, besides liberties if not global). I don't see any asynchronous behaviour here and it puzzles me how does it work.

```html
function getGroup(position, board, visited = [], group = [], liberties = 0) {
    let pointNotVisited = visited.reduce((acc, cur) => (cur.x !== position.x || cur.y !== position.y) && acc, true)
    
    if (pointNotVisited) {
        let neighbours = getNeighbours(position, board)

        group.push(position)
        visited.push(position)

        let unvisitedNeighbours = neighbours.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            let neighbourVisited = visited.filter(el => (el.x === cur.x && el.y === cur.y))
            if (neighbourVisited.length > 0) {
                return acc
            } else {
                return acc.concat(cur)
            }
        }, [])
        
        unvisitedNeighbours.forEach(stone => {
            if (stone.color == 'empty') {
                liberties++
                visited.push(stone)
            } else if (stone.color != position.color) {
                visited.push(stone)
            }
            return getGroup(stone, board, visited, group)
        })
    } else {
        return {
            'group': group,
            'liberties': liberties
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: position has a format of: { x: 1, y: 3, color: "white" }, board is used for the neighbours function. Let me know if you need any other info :) 
Please advice. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Thanks to Jaromanda X I fixed the return value issue by:

```html
unvisitedNeighbours.forEach(stone => {
    if (stone.color == 'empty') {
        liberties++
        visited.push(stone)
            // console.log('liberties after increment', liberties)
    } else if (stone.color != position.color) {
        visited.push(stone)
    }
    // console.log('liberties before recursion', liberties)
    getGroup(stone, board, visited, group, liberties)
})
return {
    "group": group,
    "liberties": liberties
}
```

however the liberties scoping issue is still there

Comment: re 2. ... it's when `if (pointNotVisited)` that the function clearly returns undefined - as there is no return statement in the "true" block

Comment: why do you `return getGroup(....` inside a forEach?

Comment: maybe i'll give some context here. It's a function which searches for a group of connected stones on a Go (chinese board game) board. I return inside because it only makes sense (to me at least) to recursively call the function on each of the neighbouring elements on the board. It is quite possible though, that I got lost somewhere inside my logic...

Comment: my point is, doing a return in `forEach` is redundant, as nothing comes of the return value

Comment: makes sense. however I'm not sure how would I call getGroup on the neighbours?

Comment: call it - I'm pointing out there's no reason for `return`, not no reason for calling `getGroup`

Comment: the main issue is that when `if (pointNotVisited) {` is true, your function `getGroup` does not return anything at all

Comment: will check it out, thx!

Comment: check what out? the `return` inside the forEach is not an issue, unless you think that's the value returned by calling `getGroup` - because it's not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154025/discussion-between-jerzyn-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the `liberties` variable in a closure using an inner function rather than trying to pass it around. It would look something like this:

```
function getGroup(position, board, visited = [], group = []) {
    var liberties = 0

    return myInnerFn(position, board, visited, group)

    function myInnerFn(position, board, visited, group) {
       // ... does grouping logic, recursively calling itself ...
    }
}
```

Here `myInnerFn` should perform all the logic you have in your `getGroups`, only `liberties` has been moved out. You may want to consider moving out other variables too, I'm not sure you need to pass around `board`, `visited` or `group` once you have a closure. I'm also guessing that `visited` and `group` will no longer be needed as arguments of the outer function, they can be created as variables just like `liberties`.

By using two functions we introduce an extra level to our variable scoping, allowing us to push the variable up out of the inner function without having to go all the way to global.

Comment: unfortunately this solution leads to 'call stack exceeded' error. I can't see why though :/

Comment: Difficult to debug without the code. I suggest you create a JSFiddle.

Comment: The inner function needs to call itself recursively, not call `getGroup`, line 104.